# How to organize Wordpress functions

Tags: wordpress

So for most Wordpress users this may sound familiar.

You make an active child-theme and a `functions.php`. After a while this php file will be filled with many action/filter hooks. Some for Wordpress itself, others for plugins. This makes it (to me) a hot mess. It's hard to keep an overview what's going on without making big blocks of comments.

How can one best approach this? I was considering turning the large `functions.php` into:

- multiple plugins
- multiple php files which are included within the `functions.php`.

What would be the best practice and give the best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an `inc` directory within your WordPress child theme's root and add categorized function files within that. Then include them in your functions.php file:

```
- js
- css
- inc
  general.php
  cpt_first.php
  cpt_second.php
  navigation.php
- ...
functions.php
```

Comment: Ofcourse tere is a whole debate about not adding every snippets to your theme's functions.php file anyways. Mainly because if you switch themes, technically you will lose all the functionality that you may not want to get rid of. If you are sure you won't switch your theme frequently, that would be a best practice. If not, make ONE plugin and do the same with your own plugin, instead of child theme. in each case avoids multiple plugins for this

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to write plugin's function in there in plugin's function file and the same for the theme. If you are gonna add any new feature in theme let say custom post type and taxonomies and you can't handle that code in function.php file then develop a plugin for custom post type and you can manage all custom post type code within that plugin. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am sorry, I find it hard to understand your answer. What you're trying to say is that; hooks for a plugin should be implemented inside the plugin and code for the theme inside the theme files? Most plugin's don't offer a place for custom php. And from what I learned so far, editing plugins is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes! keep plugin code a part from theme. And this senario is useful when you are customizing a theme and adding new features to your existing theme. 
And yes editing a plugin that's why i suggest to write your own plugin code for any new feature. And if still need to customize an existing plugin then switch auto updates off  for that plugin.